# Magento 1.7 leaves one amount in cart after successful checkout

Tags: java, ajax, magento-1.7, shopping-cart

Stackoverflow has been a great source of info, very thankful for that:)

I have one small bug in my store that I cant pinpoint.
After successful checkout when I am returned to my websites success payment/order page, everything is fine, by fine I mean that the shopping cart is empty with no items. BUT there is one amount left in the shopping cart. Only in the shopping cart indicator, as soon as you click any where that amount is gone.

Please some pointers would be forever thanked.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Would love an answer, too.